# name & register your class with a desired name not by prefix T

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-2010

Whatever component that will be created in c++ builder will be assigned TComponentName.
For example when I create a form and assign it MyWidget it then the class that inherits TForm 
gets `class TMyWidget : TForm{}` form. With spy++ like inspectors you can see registered class names of your apps.

Concerning this my question is the following.

- Is it possible at all and then how to create our forms, components
  with our desired name(excluding prefix T)?

The way I did it I created VCL Forms App and saved it. Then replaced TForm1 with my own desired classname, say, in my case `WidgetCl0x01`  in the .h,.dfm,project source file in __classid() arg but there was compilation and linking problems!

Show me directions on how to achieve this not just by changing VCL source !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the virtual `CreateParams()` method to change the classname that is assigned to the `HWND` that is allocated for the `TForm` window, eg:

```
void __fastcall TMyWidget::CreateParams(TCreateParams &Params)
{
    TForm::CreateParams(Params)
    StrLCopy(Params.WinClassName, _D("WidgetCl0x01"), (sizeof(Params.WinClassName) / sizeof(Char)) - 1);
}
```

Use the `Name` property in the Object Inspector to change the class name of the `TForm` class itself in your code, don't try to adjust it by name.  Just know that it will always be prefixed with a `T`, you cannot avoid that unless you disable the `TForm`'s DFM and create all of its content by hand in code, then the classname will not matter.

Comment: I hihgly appreciate your help! I agree with you that only overriding works here, it's a wonderful OOP feature helping us to provide our own specific implementation.

Comment: Are other controls overrided in the same way using virtual func CreateParams?(e.g.TButton,...)

Comment: All `TWinControl`-derived classes use the `CreateParams()` method.  Always call the base class `CreateParams()` first to establish defaults, then customize the `TCreateParams` as needed.